# 2D array Game Board...NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays

I need to make a board game and I started at the bottom left corner of the array [3][0] "Ursa Major". when i move "west" I get a NullPointerException. I also need some help moving diagonally to [2][1] "northeast" but not sure how to write the code for it. any help would be appreciated.

```
    //Declare Variables
    Map map;
    String input;
    Scanner scan;
    int row, col;

    //Initialize Varibales
    map = new Map();
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    row = 3; col = 0;

    //Begin user dialog
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Great Cal Poly Underground");
    input ="";
    while(!input.equals("quit"))
    {
       System.out.println(map.rooms[row][col].name);
       System.out.print(">");
       input = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase();

       if (input.equals("w"))
       {   if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("w"))
           col--;
           else
           System.out.println("You cant go that way");
       }
       else
       if (input.equals("e"))
       {   if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("e"))
           col++;
           else
           System.out.println("You cant go that way");
       }
```

that is my user interface and this is my map

```
 Room[][] rooms = new Room[4][4];

Map()
{
   Room lectureHall = new Room();
   Room cafeteria = new Room();

   lectureHall.name  = "Ursa Major";
   lectureHall.exits = new String []{"e"};//can add north south west

   cafeteria.name  = "Los Olivos";
   cafeteria.exits = new String []{"w"}; // can add north south east

   rooms[3][0] = lectureHall;
   rooms[2][1] = cafeteria;
```

and this is my Rooms

```
boolean isValidExit(String anExit)
{
    boolean result = false;
    int index = 0;
    while (result == false && index < exits.length)
    {
        if(exits[index].equals(anExit))
            result = true;
        index++;
    }     
    return result;
```

Comment: And where, amidst all this code, is the NullPointerException thrown?

Comment: can you give the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: when i am in [3][0] and try to go west the NullPointerException thrown

Comment: i tried your code and it is working fine. so unless you give us a stack trace we can't help you

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at GCPUApp.main(GCPUApp.java:25)

Comment: and its when i try to go east sorry

Answer (score 2):

`rooms` has 16 references, but only two are set (`rooms[3][0] = lectureHall; rooms[2][1] = cafeteria;`). You need to create objects for the rest of the indices.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense. so once i fill in the array list it should catch when im trying to go to a spot i cant go and say "You cant go that way" right?

Comment: Yes (considering your recent comment to your orig question: the direction is east). So with the code as you wrote it, you start at `[3][0]`, going east is allowed. But as soon as you try to call `isValidExit()` on `[3][1]`, you'll get a null pointer exception because that `Room` has not been instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing array in Java like this:

```
Room[][] rooms = new Room[4][4];
```

Only initializes the `rooms` array, meaning that only array wont be null.

However, any object "inside" it is not initialized.

If you wish to create your rooms eagerly and then set their properties, do this:

```
Room[][] rooms = new Room[4][4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        rooms[i][j] = new Room(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider all the answers above, and **also**, your starting cell is rooms[3][0], and if you want to go "west", you are decrementing col variable:

```
if (input.equals("w"))
{   if(map.rooms[row][col].isValidExit("w"))
    //you are decrementing col, which will become -1 after decrementing
    col--;
    else
       System.out.println("You cant go that way");
}
```

Then the program goes back in the loop to the beginning, where you're displaying the name of current room:

```
while(!input.equals("quit"))
{
   System.out.println(map.rooms[row][col].name);
   System.out.print(">");
```

and since col = -1, you're trying to do map.rooms[3]**[-1]**, which will definately result in an exception.

Make sure you are not referencing array indices which are < 0.